# Won't delete all files with 'delete recursive dir' function

Tags: php

I try to delete a big directory with a lot of subfolders and files (>1000). There  are many functions built for this purpose, I use the following:

```
function rrmdir($dir) {
        if (is_dir($dir)) {
            $objects = scandir($dir);
            foreach ($objects as $object) {
                if ($object != "." && $object != "..") {
                    if (filetype($dir . "/" . $object) == "dir"){
                        log_message(201,array(),'Try to delete folder: '.$dir.'/'.$object);
                        rrmdir($dir . "/" . $object);
                    }else{
                        log_message(201,array(),'Try to delete FILE: '.$dir.'/'.$object);
                        unlink($dir . "/" . $object);
                    }
                }
            }
            reset($objects);
            rmdir($dir);
        }
    }
```

The problem is, that many files are left behind. Is this usual behavior, are is something wrong with my code? If it is usual behavior, how can I get around this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to check the return value from unlink(). It'll be boolean FALSE on failure, e.g. permission denied. Just because you can SEE a file doesn't mean you can delete it too. Plus, you're not actually removing the directories you find, just the files.

Comment: listing each file to delete is not very efficient, consider the os functions available for deleting

Comment: There is no error checking in your code. so how can you expect that everyhting worked? The file-system is a system independent to your script, so it can act independent (e.g. it is even possible files are created new in directories your script thinks it has deleted already while it still runs).

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I improved the error checking and changed the filetype to is_dir function. Everything works fine now. I think it was just the particular folder I tried to delete which had wrong file permissions or something. @Dagon, could you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Different Operating handles this different. At most OS an filesystems, files can be locked exclusive for read or write operations.

If another process holds the file-handle with a lock, your process may not modify (or delete) the file. This may also be true for different threads.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't think this was the problem.